# How to go to other view when tapped imageview in a cell

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I have a table view using a custom cell (xib).

This custom cell have an image and a description.
If user tapped the image (not the cell) , it should display other page/view.

this is the function called when image tapped

```
@objc func imageTapped(){
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SbIdentifier", bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
    print("image tapped")
    //self.window?.rootViewController?.parent?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
 }
```

I tried used the push view controller but nothing happened.

Comment: are you able to see print statement log ?

Comment: yes Prashant. i could see the print statement

Comment: Instead of dealing with `self.window?.rootViewController` you can delegate to your viewcontroller which has tableiview. so it can directly push your viewcontroller. it is safe and doesn't effect the current view hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [delegate pattern](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) here to handle tap on profile image in tableViewCell to push ProfileViewController.

First create the `CellImageTappableDelegate` protocol

```
protocol CellImageTappableDelegate: class {
    func didTapProfileImage(with imageUrl: String)
}
```

then create the delegate property in Your CustomCell

```
weak var imageTapDelegate: CellImageTappableDelegate?
```

now enable `isUserInteractionEnabled` property on `UIImageView`

```
image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

then add the `tapGestureRecognizer` to your imageView and implement the selector

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(CustomProfileCell.didTapProfileImage(_:)))
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

func didTapProfileImage(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     self.imageTapDelegate?.didTapProfileImage(with: self.profileImageUrl)
}
```

in tableView datasource `cellForRowAt:` method in your `UIViewController` subclass assign the delegate to `self` and implement the protocol method

```
cell.imageTapDelegate = self

func didTapProfileImage(with imageUrl: String) {
   print("Profile image tapped")
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SbIdentifier", bundle: nil)
   let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
   profileVC.imageUrl = imageUrl
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot suhit. i missed the 'cell.imageTapDelegate'

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

RootViewController would not have a parent, which would definitely not have a navigationController. If the navigationController is the first viewController in your hierarchy, you can try:

```
(self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: ive also tried your code and this line :    
   self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

and still not working

Comment: @ChristianLeppong good that you tried it.. did it work? if not, then your view controllers hierarchy is more complex than you assume and you will have to share a bit more code so that we would be able to help you

Comment: thanks Milan. i reckoned i need to access the parent view controller because i need to push a view controller from a UITableViewCell.

Comment: @ChristianLeppong the window's rootViewController is the view controller that is the first view controller in the hierarchy of view controllers.. assumably that would be the navigation controller, in which there is embedded some other view controller (I guess your tableViewController).. there is usually just one window with many view controllers presented upon it.. you are accessing window and you are going from the root..

Comment: @ChristianLeppong I believe the best way would be setting up a delegate pattern to tell the tableViewController to present/push the view controller, but if your hierarchy is simple and you know that it won't change, this should suffice.. add the `cellForRowAt` implementation to your qustion

Comment: Instead of dealing with self.window?.rootViewController you can delegate to your viewcontroller which has tableiview. so it can directly push your viewcontroller. it is safe and doesn't effect the current view hierarchy